# Can I bypass hyper-v with an earlier version of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows, hyper-v

I installed visual studio express 2013 on my windows 8.1 computer.  Everything was fine until I learned that I needed 8.1 pro to have hyper-v to use a phone emulator to run my program. (I think)
Rather than downloading a new operating system, would I be able to use an earlier version of visual studio? If so, which one... 
I am very new to phone development and (considering I can't get past the installation stage) would appreciate the simplest explanation out there.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no. Hyper-V is a requirement for WinPhone emulation, and it requires Pro, no matter what version of VisualStudio

> Note: To use the Windows Phone 8 emulator your PC must have Windows 8
>   Pro or greater and a processor that supports Second Level Address
>   Translation (SLAT).

https://www.dreamspark.com/student/Windows-Phone-8-App-Development.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx

**However**,you can easily upgrade to Pro, see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/feature-packs You just buy an upgrade key and enter it, *you don't have to go through the whole install a new OS process*